# Textarea not getting updated text in jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

So I have a razor view:

```
@{
    int i=1;
    foreach(var story in Model.Storylines)
    {
        <span style="float:left;">Storyline @i</span> <span style="float:right; margin-right:5px;">Character Count: @story.CharCount</span><br /><br />
        <textarea id=@("entry"+@i) rows="5" style="width:730px; overflow:auto;">@story.Description</textarea><br /><br />
        i++;
    }
}
```

So the textarea with id entry1 has a description like "this is a story" when the page initially loads. Once I type something into that text area, and then hit a button whose only function is:

```
alert($("#entry1").text());
```

I still get "this is a story". Why isn't the textarea being updated with the text that I've typed in?

Comment: Seems like a jQuery bug (or quirk? :). In IE .text() returns the updated DOM value, but Chrome and FF require use of .val(). Definitely agree .val() makes sense. See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/SSYpF/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You want to use `$("#entry1").val()` to get the text within the textarea.

Comment: ARGH! I can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks.... I'll accept your answer as soon as the time limit expires.

Answer (score 6):

You will want to use `.val()` as opposed to `.text()`, as that is how to access the content of a `<textarea>`:

```
alert($("#entry1").text());
```

**should be:**

```
alert($("#entry1").val());
```

Answer (score 3):

.val will return the content of the text area

http://api.jquery.com/val/

The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements

http://api.jquery.com/text/

Unlike the .html() method, .text() can be used in both XML and HTML documents. 
The result of the .text() method is a string containing the combined text of all matched elements.

Answer (score 3):

I think text the reason why `.text()` doesn't work is because the text property gets the text value in between the textarea tag and this value is not updated when you change the value of the textarea.

The entered text is stored in the `value` attribute of the textarea control.

here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V649p/2) showing the example. jQuery's `val()` picks out the same attribute value so you may as well use `val()`